# Select field in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using a form like this, how can I change the `textboxfor`into a select, because I can't find any option to do it in the `@Html`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LeggTilUtdannelse", "Utdannelse", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "legg-til-form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Til, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Til, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: To create a dropdown, your need to use the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper. [Refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an @Html.DropDownList or @Html.DropDownListFor.